# Imfill holes won't fill every segment I need. Is there anything I can do about this? (avoiding graythresh)

Tags: matlab, object-detection, detection, image-segmentation

hope you might have a suggestion for my struggle (matlab). This is the result of the Imfill holes function, but it left a lot of segments unfilled. Is there anything I can attempt to fix this?
imfill(BW1,'holes')
[image: result]

Answer (score 4):

You may use [bwmorph](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwmorph.html) with `'bridge'` argument for bridging small gaps before `imfill`.

> **'bridge'**
> Bridges unconnected pixels, that is, sets 0-valued pixels to 1 if they have two nonzero neighbors that are not connected.

Here is a code sample:

```
I = imread('holes.jpg');

% Remove top and bottom "white frame".
I = I(7:end-6, :);

% Convert to binary image with manual threshold (could be that binarize is required only due to JPEG artifacts).
I = imbinarize(I, 0.3);

% Bridges unconnected pixels (morphological operation).
J = bwmorph(I, 'bridge');

% Fill holes
K = imfill(J, 'holes');
```

Remarks:

- Please consider posting the original image (before fill).
- Consider posting images in PNG format instead of JPEG - JPEG compression looses information and creates compression artifacts.
- The image you have posted has a "white frame", that is probably not part of the original image. I decided to keep the left and right parts for filling the shapes next to the borders.

---

Result:
[image]

Comment: Thank you so so so so so much!!  bwmorph(I, 'bridge'); is what I need! I haven't posted the original picture because these are the nuclei of cells, and I applied a bit of operations before I stuck. Or should I still post the step I was stuck at?

Comment: Your welcome. Consider my remarks when you post a new question...